# skype for bussiness-mac

Tags: mac, skype

Using my Mac I'm trying to join a conference call hosted using Skype for Business Server. I try to install the plug-ins for Skype for Business App Web-only for me (the only available option), but the installation was not successful and this message appears "you cannot install Skype for Business Web App plug-ins in this location".

Any suggestions to solve the problem?

Comment: Is this on your own Mac or is it managed by your organisation/company?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. What version of macOS and Skype for Besiness do you have?

Comment: Last time I tried to use Skype for Business on my Mac it did not work. I tried many different things. We made the call directly via telephone.